# Vertical skip for the operator \cases

Tags: cases

I would like to create a formula with the operator \cases, whose lines contain sums:

```
\begin{cases}\sum (...) \\ \sum (...) \end{cases}
```

Expressions in the sums are huge, and it would be natural to add some 'smallskip' between two lines. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd say you have (at least) two choices to get more separation between the lines of the `cases` environment:

- Insert a bit of extra space "by hand", via the optional argument to the \\ linebreak directive
- Use the `dcases` environment provided by the `mathtools` environment. Doing so achieves two purposes simultaneously -- you get better spacing between rows, and the contents are set automatically in TeX's `\displaystyle` math mode.

In the following image, the first group shows the (unsatisfactory) output of an unmodified `cases` environment; the second group shows the same overall expression but with extra spacing, in the amount of `1ex`, inserted after \\; the third group shows the output of using the `dcases` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools} 
\newcommand\bigsum{\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{i^2}} % "\sum & \frac expression"
\begin{document}
%% 0. plain 'cases'
\[
\begin{cases} \bigsum \\ \bigsum \end{cases}
\]
%% 1. 'cases' with manually set extra spacing of 1ex
\[
\begin{cases} \bigsum \\[1ex] \bigsum \end{cases}
\]
%% 2. 'dcases' (no need to insert extra spacing manually)
\[
\begin{dcases} \bigsum \\ \bigsum \end{dcases}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

The package [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools) provides a new enviroment specifically built to display equations or big symbols inside a case environment: `dcases`.

This could be a useful MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
%
\usepackage{mathtools} % automatically loads "amsmath"
%
\begin{document}
%
Standard environment:
\[
\begin{dcases}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}=2^n\\
\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=F(x)+C
\end{dcases}
\]
This is a new defined environment:
\[
\begin{dcases}
\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}=2^n\\
\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=F(x)+C
\end{dcases}
\]
%
\end{document}
```

Which gives for the output:

> [image]

An alternative would be to re-define the environment `cases` by calling it from the `mathtools` package, i.e.:

```
\@ifpackageloaded{mathtools}{%
 \renewenvironment{cases}{\begin{dcases}}{\end{dcases}}%
}{%
% doesn't do anything if the package isn't loaded
}
```

This macro could be useful inside a custom package (By the way this procedure is purely optional, since inside the LaTeX code it doesn't matter where a "d" is added inside an environment definition).

Comment: Many thanks to you too. I can accept only one answer, I am sorry.

Comment: @limanac Hehe... don't worry. The only important thing is that the main issue has been solved (I have to admit that when I started LaTeXing I had the same problem as yours).